# This is page jumps with ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I set up a tabs page, A, B, C. like this:

```
tab1Root: any = HomePage;
tab2Root: any = AboutPage;
tab3Root: any = ContactPage;
```

When I jump from PageB to a new pageC
The URL becomes：`http://localhost:8102/#/about/shopping`;
and I reload the shopping page, I have a error:

Component AboutPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
I'm newcomer, hope someone can help me;
here is my code:

about.ts:

```
  import { Component } from '';
  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
  @ionicpage()
  @component({
   selector: 'page-about',
   templateUrl: 'about.html',
  })
  export class AboutPage {
  lists = Lists
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
   NavParams) {}
  ionViewDidLoad() {}
  openPage(page){
    this.navCtrl.push(page)
   }
  }
```

about.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from './about';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
 AboutPage,
],
imports: [
 IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage),
],
})
export class AboutPageModule {}
```

Comment: @SURAJ I tried,but not work

Comment: did you remove the imports of the pages from tabs component page?

Comment: emmm....if I remove the imports . That tabs component won't find the page, so the page doesn't show

Comment: check the answer in the dupe.. you need to use string equivalents..not the page object

Comment: After the change, become a tab page has this problem

Comment: hey! I just fix the problem, just because I forget to delete Imoprt on APP COMPONENT . THX!!!

Comment: glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with tab components but I got the same error when I create a new page and I don't add it into the **entryComponents** section like:

```
import { NgModule } from '';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from './about';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
     AboutPage,
],
imports: [
     IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage),
],
entryComponents: [
     AboutPage,
]
})
```

If you declare your new page on the **EntryComponent** section should fix the issue you're having:

> AboutPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

According to the docs **EntryCompmonents**:

> Defines the components that should be compiled as well when this component is defined. For each components listed here, Angular will create a ComponentFactory and store it in the ComponentFactoryResolver.

Comment: THX! I will continue to see how to deal with my problem